# How to get client's IP in a python thrift server

Tags: python, thrift

I'm writing a thrift service in python and I would like to understand how I can 
get the client's IP address in the handler functions context.

Thanks,
Love.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the transport, and get the data from there. Not sure how to do this exactly in Python, but there's a [mailing list thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201208.mbox/%3c1345228829.17792.YahooMailNeo@web194001.mail.sg3.yahoo.com%3e) and there's [this JIRA-ticket THRIFT-1053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1053) describing a solution for C++/Java.

This is the relevant part from the mailing list thread:

> I did it by decorating the TProcessor like this psuedo-code.
>
> -craig

```
class TrackingProcessor implements TProcessor {
 TrackingProcessor (TProcessor processor) {this.processor=processor;}

 public boolean process(TProtocol in, TProtocol out) throws TException {
   TTransport t = in.getTransport();
   InetAddress ia = t instanceof TSocket ?
       ((TSocket)t).getSocket().getInetAddress() : null;
   // Now you have the IP address, so what ever you want.

   // Delegate to the processor we are decorating.
   return processor.process(in,out);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why? Because you can't translate it?

Comment: is it possible to pass ip address to server handler (Iface implementation)?

Comment: The handlers are called by the library, and the transport does not have to be an socket transport, it can be next to anything. That's basically preventing you from doing that.

Comment: @JensG What about getting the transport at service handler?

Comment: Can you show me solution with non-blocking server, because this way only works with blocking server? Non blocking server require TFramedTransport and i cannot get socket. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but I'm currently solving the same problem.
Here's my solution with thriftpy:

```
import thriftpy
from thriftpy.thrift import TProcessor, TApplicationException, TType
from thriftpy.server import TThreadedServer
from thriftpy.protocol import TBinaryProtocolFactory
from thriftpy.transport import TBufferedTransportFactory, TServerSocket

class CustomTProcessor(TProcessor):
    def process_in(self, iprot):
        api, type, seqid = iprot.read_message_begin()
        if api not in self._service.thrift_services:
            iprot.skip(TType.STRUCT)
            iprot.read_message_end()
            return api, seqid, TApplicationException(TApplicationException.UNKNOWN_METHOD), None  # noqa

        args = getattr(self._service, api + "_args")()
        args.read(iprot)
        iprot.read_message_end()
        result = getattr(self._service, api + "_result")()

        # convert kwargs to args
        api_args = [args.thrift_spec[k][1] for k in sorted(args.thrift_spec)]

        # get client IP address
        client_ip, client_port = iprot.trans.sock.getpeername()

        def call():
            f = getattr(self._handler, api)
            return f(*(args.__dict__[k] for k in api_args), client_ip=client_ip)

        return api, seqid, result, call

class PingPongDispatcher:
    def ping(self, param1, param2, client_ip):
        return "pong %s" % client_ip

pingpong_thrift = thriftpy.load("pingpong.thrift")
processor = CustomTProcessor(pingpong_thrift.PingService, PingPongDispatcher())
server_socket = TServerSocket(host="127.0.0.1", port=12345, client_timeout=10000)
server = TThreadedServer(processor,
                         server_socket,
                         iprot_factory=TBinaryProtocolFactory(),
                         itrans_factory=TBufferedTransportFactory())
server.serve()
```

Remember that every method in the dispatcher will be called with extra parameter client_ip

Answer (score -1):

The only way I found to get the `TProtocol` at the service handler is to extend the processor and create one handler instance for each client related by transport/protocol. Here's an example:

```
public class MyProcessor implements TProcessor {

    // Maps sockets to processors
    private static final Map<, Processor<ServiceHandler>> PROCESSORS = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Service.Processor<ServiceHandler>>());

    // Maps sockets to handlers
    private static final Map<String, ServiceHandler> HANDLERS = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, ServiceHandler>());

    @Override
    public boolean process(final TProtocol in, final TProtocol out)
            throws TException {

        // Get the socket for this request
        final TTransport t = in.getTransport();
        // Note that this cast will fail if the transport is not a socket, so you might want to add some checking.
        final TSocket socket = (TSocket) t; 

        // Get existing processor for this socket if any
        Processor<ServiceHandler> processor = PROCESSORS.get(socket);
        // If there's no processor, create a processor and a handler for
        // this client and link them to this new socket
        if (processor == null) {
            // Inform the handler of its socket
            final ServiceHandler handler = new ServiceHandler(socket);
            processor = new Processor<ServiceHandler>(handler);
            PROCESSORS.put(clientRemote, processor);
            HANDLERS.put(clientRemote, handler);
        }
        return processor.process(in, out);
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell Thrift to use this processor for incoming requests. For a `TThreadPoolServer` it goes like this:

```
final TThreadPoolServer.Args args = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(new TServerSocket(port));
args.processor(new MyProcessor());
final TThreadPoolServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(args);
```

The `PROCESSORS` map might look superfluous, but it is not since there's no way to get the handler for a processor (i.e. there's no getter).

Note that it is your `ServiceHandler` instance that needs to keep which socket it is associated to. Here I pass it on the constructor but any way will do. Then when the `ServiceHandler`'s `IFace` implementation is called, it will already have the associated Socket.

This also means you will have an instance of `MyProcessor` and `ServiceHandler` for each connected client, which I think is not the case with base Thrift where only one instance of each of the classes are created.

This solution also has a quite annoying drawback: you need to figure out a method to remove obsolete data from `PROCESSORS` and `HANDLERS` maps, otherwise these maps will grow indefinitely. In my case each client has a unique ID, so I can check if there are obsolete sockets for this client and remove them from the maps.

PS: the Thrift guys need to figure out a way to let the service handler get the used protocol for current call (for example by allowing to extend a base class instead of implementing an interface). This is very useful in so many scenarios.

Comment: If you are so clever why don't you provide a patch instead of trying to put other people down for no reason? We Thrift guys will be happy to review it.

Comment: Cool solution. One question though: How can this minorish issue ***This solution also has a quite annoying drawback: you need to figure out a method to remove obsolete data from PROCESSORS and HANDLERS maps*** be solved? How do I find out if an socket connection is obsolete? I can't figure it out ...

Comment: @JensG Calm down dude... I'm just saying it would be a cool feature to have since it is useful in many scenarios, I'm not putting anyone down, totally the opposite. It is just a suggestion. Thrift is an awesome project and a very powerful tool, otherwise I wouldn't be using it :)

Comment: @JensG About the obsolete data, in my case I only have a limited set of known clients, which have a unique ID. So I have 2 methods for this 1) a task that is launched periodically that checks for closed sockets and removes processors and handlers for this socket, and 2) when a client connects again, I browse both maps for its ID and remove all associated old processors and handlers. This of course means that a given client can only have 1 active connection to the server (which is OK in our model).